# Convert date format in excel from dd.mmm to dd.mm

Tags: excel, date, formatdatetime

I need to convert this data dd/mmm - 31.mar (March) to this format 31/03 - dd/mm using excel formula

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

A bit of googling would have solved your issue here.

1. Select cell (or range of cells).
2. Right click with mouse
3. Format Cells
4. Custom
5. Change Type: `dd/mmm` to `dd/mm`

   [image]

Comment: yes, i know, but i need a formula to paste it into particular cell

Comment: @ValeriaSheiko, just use the formatting in the particular cell and refernece it? eg `=A1` ???

Comment: it is not acceptable for me, i need to use this solution for bot instruction, so i need something like this: '=TIME(A1, "dd/mm")

Comment: I don't think you understand how format works. I fear I cannot help you there.

Answer (score -1):

```
=text([CellWithDate],"dd/mm")
```

is the formula you want, I think.

Comment: In fact, your approach is better than mine; just change the comma (",") for a semicolon (";"). I assume "[CellWithDate]" is meant to be replaced by "A1" in my example.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. As for the comma, that's specific to certain regions. We use commas in the US, other countries use semi-colons. It just depends on the convention that your regional settings use.

Answer (score -1):

@Valeria:

Can't be sure I understood your problem and/or the type of solution you're looking for.
I assume you have a date in , say, cell A1 and that cell is showing the date in "dd-mmm" format.
I also assume you want that date to be shown in another cell (different from A1) in "dd/mm" format BUT without previously setting that target cell format to "dd/mm".

In case I'm right, the formula you should put in the target cell shouldo look like:

```
=DAY(A1) & IF(MONTH(A1)<10;"/0";"/") & MONTH((A1))
```

This way, if cell A1 holds "31-aug", you're getting "31/08" wherever you put that formula.

The value Excel actually stores in the cell is just its date+time serial number (whatever you're seeing is a very different question). DAY() and MONTH() do work on that value to generate day of the month and month of the year after that serial number.

Hope this helps.